# Why is my Integer.parseInt not working?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, integer, syntax-error

The assignment is to create an output that reads from a file and outputs the information that is stated in the program. It was working perfectly before I went back and added the patientNumber string and the first for loop that deals with patientNumber. Now it is showing the error that the line with Integer.parseInt is not working. What happened?

```
package readfile;

import java.io.*; 
public class ReadFile {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[] patientNumber = new String [15];
    String[] patientFN = new String[15];
    String[] patientLN = new String[15];
    int[] patientBP = new int[15];
    String lastnameBP = " ";
    String all=" ";
    int x = 0;
    String Heading1 = "Patient #";
    String Heading2 = "First Name";
    String Heading3 = "Last Name";
    String Heading4 = "Patient BP";
    String Underl   = "--------------------------------------------";
    System.out.printf("%10s %10s %10s %10s", Heading1,Heading2,Heading3,Heading4);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(Underl);



   String fileName="patient.txt";
   //Name of the file with precise directory
   //String fileName="patient.txt";
   try{

      //Create object of FileReader
      FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);

      //Instantiate the BufferedReader Class
      BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

      //Variable to hold the one line data
      String line;


      // Read file line by line and print on the console
      while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)  {

          //assigning patient number, first name, last name, and BP
          for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
              if(line.charAt(i) == ' ')
              {
               patientNumber[x] = (line.substring (0,i));
               all = line.substring(i+1, line.length());
              }
          }

          for(int i=0; i<all.length(); i++)
          {
              if(all.charAt(i) == ' ')
              {
                  patientFN[x] = all.substring(0,i);
                  lastnameBP = all.substring(i+1, all.length());
                  break; //breaking loop

              }
          }
              for(int i =0; i < lastnameBP.length();i++) {
             if(lastnameBP.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                 patientLN[x]= lastnameBP.substring(0, i);
                 patientBP[x] = Integer.parseInt(lastnameBP.substring(i + 1, lastnameBP.length()));
                 break;
             }
              }
     x++;
             }
      //Close the buffer reader
      bufferReader.close();
   }catch(IOException e){ 
     //At the top print your titles with format characters
     // Each column is 10 Characters and left justified ("%-10s")   
       System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" + e.getMessage());                      
   }  
   for(int k=0; k< 15; k++) {
        System.out.printf("&-10s", patientNumber[k]);
        System.out.printf("%-10s", patientFN[k]);
        System.out.printf("%-10s", patientLN[k] );
        System.out.printf("%-10s", patientBP[k] );
        System.out.println();
 }    
}   
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Patient # First Name  Last Name Patient BP
--------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
string: ""
at 

java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString 
(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at readfile.ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:74)
C:\Users\wking\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-
snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: And what is the value of the string that you're trying to parse as an integer?  Hint: That value doesn't represent an integer.

Comment: @David I am not sure what you're asking. It worked with that value prior to me editing it. The edit shouldn't have had any effect on this part.

Comment: It says it right there in your exception, an empty string can't be parsed as an integer. What would you expect?

Comment: @WJK: What I'm asking is... What is the value of the string that you're trying to parse as an integer?  For example, if the value was `"1"` then you could parse that to the integer `1`.  The now-formatted error message is telling you that the value was `""`.  What integer value do you expect that to be?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have trouble with finding the number you want to parse. May I suggest you simplify your main loop to something like the following:

```
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)  {
    String[] parts = line.trim().split(" ");
    patientNumber[x] = parts[0];
    patientFN[x] = parts[1];
    patientLN[x] = parts[2];
    patientBP[x] = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
    x++;
}
```